# How to add parameters to Get with add_headers

Tags: r, xml, httr

I'm trying to download xml API with R,

the following script is working

```
commission_junction_token <-"XXX" 
commission_junction_url <-"https://commission-detail.api.cj.com/v3/commissions?date-type=posting&start-date=2016-07-01&end-date=2016-07-06"

xmlInternalTreeParse(GET(add_headers(Authorization=commission_junction_token),url=commission_junction_url))
```

but what i'm trying to do is to add the dates parameters in a query, something like that:

```
    from <- Sys.Date()-5
    to <- Sys.Date()-1
    xmlInternalTreeParse(
  GET(add_headers(Authorization=commission_junction_token),
      query=list(url=commission_junction_url,
                 start-date=from,
                 end-date=to)))
```

but i'm receiving an error , how can i insert the start-date and the end-date fields as parameters ?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are receiving? It is an R error or is it an error in the response from the server? Do you just need to quote your list names (ie `"start-date"=from`)?

Comment: it's an r error , attached :Error: unexpected '=' in:
"query=list(url=commission_junction_url,
start-date="

Comment: Then your problem is likely in your query list. You are trying to build a named list with invalid names. Just but quotes around the names with dashes in them as i described above. Also, you probably just want to have querystring parameters in the `query=` parameter and move the base URL outside that parameter.

Comment: thanks i moved the URL outside and put the start-dare and end-date inside ` and now its working